# Dual meaning of 'Latest'

Tags: word-choice, ambiguity

I want to sort a list of events chronologically in 'latest first' order. Does this mean the most recent events will be the top of the list, or the bottom of the list?

Latest means 'most recent', but it could also be interpreted means the 'most late'? i.e. the complete opposite.

What might be better terms to describe the orders of a chronologically and reverse chronologically sorted list in layman's terms?

Comment: ***Latest*** means the most recent, the other connotation is used in expressions like "at the latest".http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/latest - The latest event is the most recent event, no misunderstanding.

Comment: The interpretation of latest="the most late" is possible, but only in specific contexts which are fairly rare. For instance: *He always arrives late every day, and this is the latest he's ever been*. This would only be used in contexts where there is no possibility of confusion with the far more common meaning of "most recent". So the example you gave would be understood as "most recent", without ambiguity.

Comment: Am I missing something? Most late = most recent. If event E happens after events F and G (all happening in the past, i.e. before 'now'), then the most late is E, and the most recent is also E.

Comment: @Lawrence - As others mentioned above, in some contexts - rightly or wrongly - 'late' and 'latest' can sometimes be used to indicate the least-recent of something. I'm aware this doesn't fir the usual definition, but I'm trying to avoid being ambiguous for the few who may misinterpret it.

Comment: @Barguast That might be conflating *oldest* with *latest*. In any case, it's good to strive to be clear, as you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What might be better terms to describe the orders of a chronologically
>   and reverse chronologically sorted list in layman's terms?

Sorted by date, most recent first.

Reverse sorted by date, oldest first.

Comment: Thanks, these are the terms I ended up going with. Particularly since the emphasis is on what comes first (so I didn't need to use 'most recent last')